# Compute the determinant of $A$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> How to prove that the determinant of the following matrix
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> a&-b&-c&-d\\
> b&a&d&-c\\
> c&-d&a&b\\
> d&c&-b&a
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> is $\det A=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$?

Note that $AA^t=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)I_4$, but we just have to $$|\det A|=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Recall $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ so you just need to figure out the sign of $\det(A)$

Comment: But how to prove that $\det A>0$?

Comment: This has appeared here, IIRC. One way to pin the sign down is to use indeterminates for $a,b,c,d$. The sign must be the same for all $a,b,c,d$, so you can get it right by setting $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=0$ and $d=0$ and checking what sign you get then.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach: If $A,B,C,D$ are square matrices and $CD=DC$, then
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}=\det(AD-BC).$$
Letting
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}-c&-d\\d&-c\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}c&-d\\d&c\end{pmatrix},D=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix},$$
you can check that $CD=DC$ and thus compute
$$\det(AD-BC)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2&0\\0&a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix}=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.$$

Comment: Wikipedia gives [theorem 3](http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf) as a reference for the identity, but anyone with a nicer reference should chime in

Comment: The reference you have used is also available at HAL: [John Silvester, *Determinants of Block Matrices*, hal-01509379](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01509379/), which is perhaps a more long-lived URL.